# Find all pairs of positive integers $(x,y)$ : $x(x+1) = y(y+1)(y+2)$

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

Find all pairs of positive integers $(x,y)$ : $$x(x+1) = y(y+1)(y+2)$$

I was able to find only two pairs: $(2,1)$ and $(14,5)$ and looks like no more exists.
How to prove it?

Comment: See [this paper](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.pjm/1103034569) by L. J. Mordell

Comment: @mathlove, got it., thanks.